# Create a list of objects representing changes between a list of objects

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET 4.7.2.

I have this code which should document changes between `Person` objects:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FromValue { get; set; }
    public string ToValue { get; set; }
}

public class ChangesCalculator
{
    public List<Change> GetChanges(List<Person> people)
    {
        var changes = new List<Change>();

        for (int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
        {
            var toChange = people[i];
            var fromChange = people[i + 1];

            var wasNameUpdated = toChange.Name != fromChange.Name;
            var wasAgeUpdated = toChange.Age != fromChange.Age;

            if (wasNameUpdated)
            {
                var change = new Change
                {
                    FieldName = "Name of person", // unfortunately this can't be the same as the field name
                    FromValue = fromChange.Name,
                    ToValue = toChange.Name
                };
                changes.Add(change);
            }

            if (wasAgeUpdated)
            {
                var change = new Change
                {
                    FieldName = "Age of person",
                    FromValue = fromChange.Age.ToString(),
                    ToValue = toChange.Age.ToString()
                };
                changes.Add(change);
            }
        }

        return changes;
    }
}
```

The issue is, when more properties are added to the `Person` class, more `if` statements will need to be created in `GetChanges()`.

If `Change.FieldName` had the same value as the actual field name, it should be easy to do with reflection, but unfortunately this is not the case.

Is there some way I can write this better so I don't need to keep writing `if` statements for newly added properties?

Comment: So  the value assigned to `FieldName` will be `Name` or `Age` - the `Person` property names themselves, yes?

Comment: @radarbob Unfortunately not, if it's "Age" then the fieldname should be "Age of person" etc.
This is a simplified example of a more complicated scenario I have on my current project, where the field name needs to be displayed slightly differently.

Comment: How about a `Dictionary` of paired property names? No `if`ing at all.

Comment: `field name needs to be displayed slightly differently.`  ->  is this for a printed report?  [Use string interpolation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation), maybe?

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used.

Comment: What version of .net are you using?  We use source generators to make IEqualityComparer for several of our classes.

Comment: @CharlesNRice I'm using .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: The code is also broken since it accesses an index out of bounds on last loop iteration. Since the code was obviously not tested it makes it somewhat off-topic here I believe (admittedly it's a simple fix)

Comment: For your main question though - I think the answer is to use Reflection and iterate over all properties on the type and compare the values between the two objects. Combine it with a custom attribute that you can set on each property that specifies the desired "Change Field Name".

Comment: If you do this check a lot and in 4.7.2 I would recommend expression trees.  You can then do reflection once and reuse the func over and over again.  There is a performance cost of expression trees so it's only worth it if the comparison is used a lot.